# Splitting a comma separated string and extracting specific values

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a query that concatenates the values of two columns and returns a string as shown below:

```
423545(50),AXX-10, ABB-1234X(30), 7568787(50),53654656,2021947(50),ABCD-2343423,FDKHD-324342(20),
```

I would like to split that string and put it in an array discarding all the values in the brackets. The output to be as shown below:

```
[423545,AXX-10, ABB-1234X, 7568787,53654656,2021947,ABCD-2343423,FDKHD-324342]
```

- The comma at the end of the string is optional
- Not all the columns contain the bracketed values

I know i can use String.split() but the optional bracketed values and comma at the end of the string complicates it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on two patterns: -

- One on `\\(\\d+\\),[ ]*`, which will take care of bracketed terms
- Secondly on `,[ ]*`, which will work for normal `,` separated values.

You just need to merge those regex using a `pipe(|)`, and perform the split at once.

So, your split criteria becomes: -

```
str.split("(?:\\(\\d+\\),[ ]*)|(?:,[ ]*)");
```

which can be further simplified to: -

```
str.split("(?:\\(\\d+\\))?,[ ]*");
```

We just made a part optional, and took the common part outside.

Comment: Which is equivalent to `(?:\\(\\d+\\))?,[ ]*` due to left to right scanning.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't really matter... Depending on how one reads the regex, the intent in yours might be easier to read, since the first item is always tried first before the other.

Comment: @nhahtdh.. Yeah, but still, that was really unnecessary repetition. And thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: wouldnt d+ only pick digits? What would be the effect if i used w+ for alphanumerics?

Comment: @ziggy.. You can use anything in place of `\d+`. That will anyways extract content inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
([a-zA-Z\-\d]+)[()\d]*,*
```

? I tested it [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html), and it seems to work: you get the token to insert in the result string in the group no.1, if the zeroth is the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the values in parens, and then split.

```
    String str = "423545(50),AXX-10, ABB-1234X(30), 7568787(50),53654656,2021947(50),ABCD-2343423,FDKHD-324342(20)";

    String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)", "");
    for (String string : str2.split(",")) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```